# Validation error: "Password can't be blank" but it isn't blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It keeps saying that the password field and the password_confirmation field is blank, even when I use the rails console to create a new user. Also, the error message for the password confirmation repeats and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLuSt.png)

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  attr_accessor :password
  validates :password, length: 6..100, confirmation: true
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
  before_save :encrypt_password
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, if: lambda {| u| u.password.present? }


  def encrypt_password
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)

  end
end
```

User controller

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save and user.valid?
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      render 'users/new'
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.required(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

User/Sign-up view

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "signup.css" %>

<div id = signup_image></div>
<div id = signup-background>
  <div id = signup-text>
    <h1 style = "color: rgb(40,50,60);">Sign up</h1>
    <%= form_for :user,url: '/users' do |f| %>
      <br> <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", class: 'signup-textfield'%><br>
      <br><%= f.text_field :email, placeholder:"email@gmail.com", class: 'signup-textfield' %><br>
      <br><%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password",class: 'signup-textfield' %><br>
      <br><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm password",class: 'signup-textfield' %><br>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit id: "signup-button"%>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <small>Already have an account?  <%=link_to "Login here", "/login" %></small>
  </div>
</div>
```

User new view

```
<div id = signup_image></div>
<div id = signup-background>
  <div id = signup-text>
    <h1 style = "color: rgb(40,50,60);">Sign up</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <%= render :partial => 'shared/error_message_form' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <br> <%= f.text_field :name , placeholder: "Name", class: 'signup-textfield'%>
        <br><%= f.text_field :email,  placeholder:"email@gmail.com", class: 'signup-textfield' %>
        <br><%= f.password_field :password_digest, placeholder: "Password",class: 'signup-textfield' %>
        <br><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm password",class: 'signup-textfield' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit id: "signup-button"%>
    <% end %>
    <br><br>

    <small>Already have an account?  <%=link_to "Login here", "/login" %></small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Partial for Error Message

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")%> detected while signing up.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <br>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li>* <%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

en.yml file

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Email address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "cannot be empty"
              taken: "%{value} is already taken"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole host of problems here which is quite normal if you're new.

### Model

This is actually all you need:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, 
      format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }
end
```

- [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) sets up password encryption for you. You don't manually need to encrypt the password. Neither do you need to setup any validations as it already sets them up for you:

  - Password must be present on creation
  - Password length should be less than or equal to 72 bytes
  - Confirmation of password (using a XXX_confirmation attribute)
- If you want to provide your own validation logic you should use `has_secure_password(validations: false)` to avoid duplicate validations. But learn to use the framework first.
- Using `attr_accessor :password` just clobbers the setter created by `has_secure_password`. It should almost never be used in models.
- Only validating the email format on creation makes no sense.

### Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Welcome! ...' 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    # the method is called require not required
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

- `.save` calls `.valid?` before it attempts to save the record. Thus `@user.save and user.valid?` is totally superflouos. You should also always check the return value of `.save` and not `.valid?` as in some rare cases the validations might pass but the DB might still reject the insert query.
- Use `&&` and not the `and` keyword as the later has a different operator preceedence.
- You should redirect the user somewhere meaningful after signup instead of `render 'users/new'`.
- `render 'users/new'` and render `render :action => "new"` are both overly explict versions of `render :new`.

### View

Don't repeat the form. Use a partial:

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'signup-textfield'%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "email@example.com", class: 'signup-textfield' %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password %>
     <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'signup-textfield' %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'signup-textfield' %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit id: "signup-button" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

```
<div id = signup_image></div>
<div id = signup-background>
  <div id = signup-text>
    <h1 style = "color: rgb(40,50,60);">Sign up</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
          <%= render partial: 'shared/error_message_form' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user } %>
    <small>Already have an account?  <%=link_to "Login here", "/login" %></small>
  </div>
</div>
```

- You're missing the input for the password!
- Do not use an input for the password digest! Its generated on the server from the cleartext input and should never actually be exposed to the user.
- Stop using `<br>` tags. Use content tags (for example `<div>`) to wrap inputs and labels so that it can be styled with CSS, its not 2005 anymore. `<br>` should only be used to break text into lines. Not for visual spacing.
- Do not use the `placeholder` attribute instead of labels. Its [an anti-pattern thats horrible for usability and accessibility](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/#:%7E:text=The%20placeholder%20attribute%20contains%20a,delivering%20on%20what%20it%20promises.&text=Introduced%20as%20part%20of%20the,the%20control%20has%20no%20value.).
- Use convention over configuration and just pass the model instance to `form_with` / `form_for`. Rails can figure out the path on its own. Avoid calling form for with a symbol - `form_for :user`. The instance variable / method lookup performed is less explicit and considered a case of rails magic gone to far. This behavior was not carried over to `form_with`.
- Do you REALLY need a separate User/Sign-up view which duplicates the whole thing?